# Can PathParam be ever used without any parameter in Path annotation?

Tags: java, spring, rest, annotations, path-parameter

I am aware about the usage of PathParam annotation and the standard way to utilize it is :

```
@Path(/data/{id})
... getData(@PathParam("id") String id){...}
```

Can I use PathParam without a parameter in Path annotation? For eg:

```
@Path(/data)
... getData(@PathParam("id") String id){...}
```

If yes, what does the value of the string id depict?

Comment: It gives error in Spring Boot - `MissingPathVariableException: Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type String`. `@Path` and `@PathParam` are of JAX-RS, not Spring, but the behaviour should be the same I think. Why don't you try running it instead of posting a question?

Comment: I got a code snippet which is functional and is of the same pattern mentioned in the question. Hence the question. Must be that the value is being carried forward from parent class.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to achieve is have an optional path parameter named `id`. You can achieve that using the following path param with regex:

```
@Path(/data/{id : (.+)?})
... getData(@PathParam("id") String id){...}
```

This way, `id` will be `null` if no path param is provided. Otherwise the provided value will be given.

Comment: okay. So, I believe implementing pathParam implies having a parameter in Path annotation, which could be made optional as you suggested. If the value is missing, it will throw an exception suggested in the comment by @Kartik.

Comment: If you used in the way suggested by @Kartik, then it will throw an exception. But with my approach, it will only be `null`. So, if the value is missing, you will get a `null` for `id`. You will need to check for null within the method.